# How to set a Int property of a control on ASCX?

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties

I have an ASCX that contains

```
<my:Foo ID="Bar" runat="server" Value='' />
```

I want to set `Value` with `textbox1.Text`, but `Value` is an Int32. I am looking for something like this:

```
<my:Foo ID="Bar" runat="server" Value='<%= Int32.Parse(textbox1.Text) %>' />
```

But I get

```
Parser Error Message: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Int32' from its string representation '<%= Int32.Parse(textbox1.Text) %>' for the 'Value' property.
```

Is there a way to do this on the ASCX file? Do I have to implement a TypeConverter for this property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't understand why you can't simply use the literal instead of a string representation:

```
<my:Foo ID="Bar" runat="server" Value="58" />
```

If you want to set this value dynamically, you will need to do so in the code behind or within a code block, for example in the page load event handle, as you cannot use code blocks (`<%%>`) within a server side control:

```
// code behind, in the page_load event handler
Bar.Value = 58;
```

Or, within the `ascx`, outside of server side controls:

```
<% Bar.Value = 58; %>
```

Comment: So it's not possible to set `Value` with `textBox1.Text` value on the ASCX file?

Comment: You can do it withing a code block, so long as it is _outside_ the control. See updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

Change it to

```
<my:Foo ID="Bar" runat="server" Value="58" />
```

The ASP.Net parser will automatically parse integer properties.

`<%= ... %>` expressions aren't supported for server-side controls, so your code causes ASP.Net to try (and fail) to parse the literal string `<%= Int32.Parse("58") %>` as an integer.